# Find out if a geographic position is within a given distance of the line between two other positions

Tags: python, gps, coordinates

For a robotics project, I need to determine if a given geographic position is within a certain distance of the line between two waypoints.

The line represents a corridor of a given width. I need a function to return True if I am inside the corridor, False if I am outside.

This situation would return True:

[image: corridor]

This situation would return False:

[image: corridor]

Comment: Please provide the code you worked on. You can refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . The more details you provide, the more we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited after comment)

[image: schema]

Given the picture above, your problem reduces to a simple trigonometric problem. You essentially need to calculate `d` and then compare it to `h`. If `d` is greater and `h` then the point `C` is outside the corridor, otherwise, the point `C` is inside the corridor.

## Calculating `d`

Calculating `d` is as simple as applying a few trigonometric identities.

First, you know that the dot product of the vectors `AB` and `AC` is given by:

[image: equation]

which allows you to calculate`a`:

[image: cosa]

Then using the usual trigonometric relations, you get:

[image: cosa]

which turns into:

[image: cosa]

which you can calculate since you have an expression for `a`.

## Calculating `d'`

This is again nothing but simple trigonometry:

[image: cosa]

## Predicate function

This function takes at least 4 arguments as inputs:

2. `h` - the width of the corridor
3. `A` - the coordinates of point A
4. `B` - the coordinates of point B
5. `C` - the coordinates of point C

Within the function, you need to:

1. Calculate the vectors `AB` and `AC`
2. Calculate `d`
3. Calculate `d'`
4. If `d'` < 0 or `d'` > ||AB||, return false
5. If `d` <= `h` return true, false otherwise

Taking the size of the `A`, `B` and `C` if you know their shape is not too complicated. Essentially, you need to modify the tests at points 4 and 5 above to take the actual size of the objects into considerations.

(e.g. if you assume that `A` and `C` are spheres, then you need to make sure that hh < `d'` < ||AB|| - hh, where hh is the sum of the radii of `A` and `C`)

Comment: It's a good start, but it does not rule out the case where (d <= h AND C is "outside" the segment). Examples: on your schema, if C was positioned to the left of A, or to the right of B.
Additionally, it does not take into account the rounding around A and B, as illustrated on my sketch.

Comment: I've just spotted a mistake, which I now fixed. Making sure that `C` is "between" `A` and `B` can be done as shown above. Taking the sizes into account can also be done quite easily if you know the shapes of A, B and C, but I'll let you do that on your own.